# WiFi connection much slower on 14.04 than windows

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, resolv.conf

I just installed Ubuntu and am very new to it, but my connection is super slow: downloading  at a rate of 8kb/s whereas on Windows I download a rate of 4MB/s on a 70mbps internet connection.

*How should I proceed?*

**`lspci -v`**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 0100  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: snb_uncore  

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core   Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0  
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0  
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff  
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff  
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport  

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1c3a  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27  
    Memory at f710a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me  

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1c2d  
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16  
    Memory at f7108000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci  

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 3662  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28  
    Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel  

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0  
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport  

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0  
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0  
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff  
    Memory behind bridge: f2000000-f20fffff  
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f2100000-00000000f21fffff  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport  

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1c26  
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23  
    Memory at f7107000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci  

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC   Controller (rev 05)  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1c5c  
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich  

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1c02  
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25  
    I/O ports at f070 [size=8]  
    I/O ports at f060 [size=4]  
    I/O ports at f050 [size=8]  
    I/O ports at f040 [size=4]  
    I/O ports at f020 [size=32]  
    Memory at f7106000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: ahci  

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1c22  
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10  
    Memory at f7105000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]  
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]  

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GTX 650] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])  
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology Device 0fc6  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29  
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]  
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]  
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]  
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]  
    Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau  

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)  
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology Device 0fc6  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17  
    Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel  

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many)  
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26  
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]  
    Memory at f2110000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]  
    Memory at f2100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]  
    Expansion ROM at f2000000 [disabled] [size=64K]  
    Capabilities: <access denied>  
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**`wireless-info.txt`**:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 19 Aug 2015 02:49 IDT +0300

Booted last: 19 Aug 2015 02:41 IDT +0300

Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many) [1849:8168] Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1532:0037 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU    802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0951:16a4 Kingston Technology 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1e7d:3264 ROCCAT 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0291 Microsoft Corp. Xbox 360 Wireless    Receiver for Windows
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8192cu              69632  0 
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                73728  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              708608  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              524288  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.100.102.6  Bcast:10.100.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3970585 (3.9 MB)  TX bytes:631499 (631.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Ravid1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Ravid1'  [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.100.102.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.100.102.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       767     1  0 02:41 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [Ravid1]  ------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           65 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Puff:            Infra, <MAC 'Puff' [AC2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 87 WPA WPA2
    Olga:            Infra, <MAC 'Olga' [AC4]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 47 WPA WPA2
    Berdichevski:    Infra, <MAC 'Berdichevski' [AC3]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA WPA2
    HOTFiber-20:     Infra, <MAC 'HOTFiber-20' [AC5]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA WPA2
    *Ravid1:         Infra, <MAC 'Ravid1' [AC1]>, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.100.102.6
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.100.102.1

    DNS:             127.0.0.1
    DNS:             10.100.102.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############


##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ravid1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ravid1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Ravid1 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/RavidWiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=RavidWiFi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=RavidWiFi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jerusalem (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Ravid1' [AC1]>
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ravid1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000047a7f514f4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 108ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Puff' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Puff"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000165fe603f58
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1372ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'Berdichevski' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=12/70  Signal level=-98 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Berdichevski"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002eab1c53aa
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1700ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'Olga' [AC4]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Olga"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000028a4156db7
                    Extra: Last beacon: 292ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'HOTFiber-20' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=12/70  Signal level=-98 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"HOTFiber-20"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000120f49a7224
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8192cu]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
srcversion:     3E8327A34276F37FFE5A6A8
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,rtl_usb,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:AA:11:D1:8C:2D:3A:40:B1:B4:DB:E5:BF:8A:D6:56:DD:F5:18:38
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0) (bool)  
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko
description:    USB basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     814A6FB8DBFFB696F45B316
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:                        6A:AA:11:D1:8C:2D:3A:40:B1:B4:DB:E5:BF:8A:D6:56:DD:F5:18:38
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl8192c_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     134BAE300AAF914967D6C6C
depends:        rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        6A:AA:11:D1:8C:2D:3A:40:B1:B4:DB:E5:BF:8A:D6:56:DD:F5:18:38
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     35016235A31CEB1854418E1
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:   6A:AA:11:D1:8C:2D:3A:40:B1:B4:DB:E5:BF:8A:D6:56:DD:F5:18:38
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B23264F074A7D27F8B691A2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:            6A:AA:11:D1:8C:2D:3A:40:B1:B4:DB:E5:BF:8A:D6:56:DD:F5:18:38
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     E61EB836E1B33C2A2918485
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:            6A:AA:11:D1:8C:2D:3A:40:B1:B4:DB:E5:BF:8A:D6:56:DD:F5:18:38
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8192cu]
debug: 0
swenc: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf]
options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    6.328144] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x11
[    6.404643] rtl8192cu: MAC address: <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[    6.404646] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[    6.404890] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[    6.404911] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[    6.488446] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   10.954510] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   10.987128] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   13.079668] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'Ravid1' [AC1]>
[   13.093895] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'Ravid1' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   13.104049] wlan0: authenticated
[   13.105822] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'Ravid1' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   13.111448] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Ravid1' [AC1]>    (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   13.112193] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please open a terminal (search for a programm named "gnome shell" or "xterm") and enter `lspci -v". Post the output into your question. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question and provide the output to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) instead of @Ben's proposal.

Comment: There is a post on the ubuntuusers forum [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2201556&p=12922180#post12922180] (last of the thread). He made modifications to some specific config files. Can you try to check if this works for you?

Comment: I think you are running nito the same issue, because your nameserver 127.0.1.1 is definitly wrong.

Comment: @Ben when doing that the internet connection doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver by running in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: first one worked, the last 2 returned this: 
  
    ravid@ravid-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update  
    E: Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)  
    E: The list of sources could not be read.  
    ravid@ravid-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware  
    Reading package lists... Error!  
    E: Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)  
    E: The list of sources could not be read.  
    E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Please create a new question. `add-apt-repository` creates a new file in folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, so this is probably an other issue.

Comment: @Ben honestly i think i wasted enough time trying to solve this, it doesn't seem to ever get solved, i guess I'll just stick to windows. feels like a waste of time for me

Comment: Sure. Just make sure you blame hardware vendors, not linux itself. ;-)