# In ubuntu 14.04, why does my internet connection keep disconnecting?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

what could be causing repeated internet connection dropping on a wireless network (the wireless does not disconnect), which can be momentarily fixed by disconnecting and reconnecting in 14.04? Here is the wireless info list http://pastebin.com/ZgGxQ9qE

I am using a USB TP-Link TL-WN821N wireless adapter (Realtek rtl8192cu).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) too...

Comment: @Pilot6 - hi, I tried that command but it prints nothing on the terminal, if I type just `lspci -knn` there is a long list.

Comment: Are you using a USB wireless adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 - yes, it is a TP-Link TL-WN821N. But the wireless connection does not disconnect, I can ping the router at its ip address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WiFi connection much slower on 14.04 than windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/662901/wifi-connection-much-slower-on-14-04-than-windows)

Comment: Install the driver as directed in the duplicate link.

Comment: @Pilot6 - hi, I'm doing as you suggested, but my internet speed isn't slow, it disconnects completely, even though the computer is still connected to the wireless network. When I disconnect and reconnect the internet is back and the speed is as fast as ever.

Comment: It does not matter. There may be various symptoms with the default driver.

Comment: OK. The question is not duplicate, but the answer is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the driver by running in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

Then reboot.